# Find the period of a limit cycle computed through numerical integration

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, numerical-methods, computer-science, stability-in-odes

I numerically integrated a 3-equation non-linear ODE system in the form:

$$ dx/dt = f_1(x,y,z) \\
dy/dt = f_2(x,y,z)\\
dz/dt = f_3(x, y, z)$$

whose appear to be stabilizing on a periodic orbit. How can i estimate the period of this orbit only looking at the sequence of "points" that i generated? I tried to register the position $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ at a certain time $T_1$, then register the time $T_2$ where my integration produces a point $(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ that is in a "small" region around the first point, getting the period as $T = T_1 - T_2$. This approach generates strange behaviour sometimes, and i can't find anywhere a consistent method to get the unknown period of a periodic orbit. Can anyone help?

EDIT: got a new idea, can i watch the points in the phase space $(x, dx/dt)$ computed in discrete time to get the period?

Comment: Without telling anything about your system it is very difficult to help. But in general, you could try to use the method of harmonic balance to get an approximation for the frequency/period or multiple scales for better results.

Comment: Use the plane that is perpendicular to the trajectory at $(x_1,y_1,z_1)$. Ideally you would also approximate the Jacobian of the map of the plane into itself following the trajectories for one period. Then analyse the eigenvalues of the Jacobian.

Comment: The problem is that I don't have enough mathematical background to be able to use efficiently this methods

Comment: You can numerically solve the system $$ \eqalign{\dfrac{dt}{dx} &= \dfrac{1}{f_1(x,y,z)}\cr \dfrac{dy}{dx} &= \dfrac{f_2(x,y,z)}{f_1(x,y,z)}\cr \dfrac{dz}{dx} &= \dfrac{f_3(x,y,z)}{f_1(x,y,z)}}$$  near  $(x_2, y_2, z_2, T_2)$ to get the time near $T_2$ when $x = x_1$.